# Using Eclipse and eGit - after the initial setup, how do I tell what protocol is being used, i.e. ssh or not?

Tags: eclipse, git

We have a small team of developers working on a project that works with a Git repository hosted by TFS that is already owned by the customer. We are using Eclipse and eGit. How can I tell what protocol is being used when we do pull and push? I can see the URL but i'm not sure how to tell what the protocol is.. I'm interested in knowing if SSH is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git remote get-url --all origin
```

will to display information about URLs of the remote. If they start with `https` then http is used. If they start with `user@server.domain` then, most likely, ssh is used.

Comment: Thanks but we are mandated to use eGit - is there a way to tell from there? Thanks

Comment: Sure. It is displayed in `Git repositories` view. Expand `Remotes` section of your repo to see the URLs.

Comment: thanks. yes the URL said:  https://tfs.thesite.com/tfs/GitCollection/Project1/Project1%20Team/_git/ABC